# php preg_match get unmatched text

Tags: php

i am using preg_match function and i want to get the unmatched text with it.
This is my code:

```
<?php
$subject = "abcdef ghij";
$pattern = '/^def/';
preg_match($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);

print_r($matches);
?>
```

Can i retrieve the part of the string, that is not matching "abcdef" in the above string, using preg_match?

Comment: Please list some more possible strings and what you want to extract them from. That way we can find a more appropriate regex.

Comment: I have added my code, please see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simpler way is to split string ( explode or preg_split ), then run foreach and remove unmatched parts

```
$subject = "abcdef ghij";
$subject = explode( " ", $subject );
foreach( $subject as $k => $v ) if( preg_match( "/abcdef/", $v )) {
  unset( $subject[$k] );
}
$subject = implode( " ", $subject );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$subject = "abcdef ghij";
$key = 'def';
$non_match = '';
if(preg_match("/^(.*)$key(.*)$/",$subject,$m)) {
        $non_match= $m[1].$m[2];
}
```

Comment: Works too, but pity i can accept only 1 answer in stackoverflow :)